# How to "reverse" a simple 2 column relationship table

Tags: mysql, sql

Good evening,

I'm new to SQL.

I've been trying to "reverse" a  a simple 2 column relationship table.

Here is an example to explain it :

TABLE KnowEachOther

```
¦     id_human1   ¦     id_human2      ¦
¦        1        ¦         10         ¦
¦        1        ¦         11         ¦
¦        2        ¦         12         ¦
¦        2        ¦         13         ¦
```

So here I have a table of people that know each other. Each line means humanX and humanY know each other. Now I want to get a table of people that don't know each other ( assuming this table has all the people ). This would give this :

TABLE DontKnowEachOther

```
¦     id_human1   ¦     id_human2      ¦
¦        1        ¦          2         ¦
¦        1        ¦         12         ¦
¦        1        ¦         13         ¦
¦        2        ¦         10         ¦
¦        2        ¦         11         ¦
¦        11       ¦         10         ¦
¦        12       ¦         10         ¦
¦        13       ¦         10         ¦
¦        11       ¦         12         ¦
¦        11       ¦         13         ¦
¦        12       ¦         13         ¦
```

Any hints on how to do that would be appreciated. What would be even more appreciated is how you approach such non-trivial task. Trying to get better here ;).

Many thanks

Comment: Cross join and outer join where null

Comment: Do you have a different 'Human' Table that lists all their ID's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let us begin with something you forgot.  (If you really don't want to have this, it can be computed from the tables you gave, but it is surely better to have it.)

```
CREATE TABLE Humans 
  (
    id int PRIMARY KEY
  );

INSERT INTO Humans (id) VALUES (1),(2),(11),(12),(13);
```

Then, here is your table and data:

```
CREATE TABLE KnowEachOther 
  (
    id1 INT,
    id2 INT,
    PRIMARY KEY ( id1, id2 )
  );

INSERT INTO KnowEachOther (id1, id2) VALUES
 (1,10),
 (1,11),
 (2,12),
 (2,13);
```

Then, we can declare the following very useful view of all possible relationships:

```
CREATE VIEW AllPossibleRelationships AS SELECT
    h1.id AS id1,
    h2.id AS id2
FROM Humans AS h1 
    CROSS JOIN Humans AS h2
WHERE h1.id <> h2.id;
```

And then, we can create a view which removes from "all possible relationships" those rows for which there exist relationships.  (See `WHERE k.id1 IS NULL`)

```
CREATE VIEW DontKnowEachOther AS SELECT 
    a.id1 AS id1, 
    a.id2 AS id2
FROM AllPossibleRelationships AS a 
    LEFT JOIN KnowEachOther AS k
        ON (a.id1 = k.id1 AND a.id2 = k.id2) OR 
           (a.id1 = k.id2 AND a.id2 = k.id1)
WHERE k.id1 IS NULL
ORDER BY a.id1;
```

So, executing `SELECT * FROM DontKnowEachOther;` yields the following:

```
id1 id2
1   2
1   12
1   13
2   1
2   11
11  2
11  12
11  13
12  1
12  11
12  13
13  1
13  11
13  12
```

Note: there is a bit of ambiguity with respect to the contents of your `KnowEachOther` table and what it means to "know each other".  "Knowing each other" is an undirected relationship, meaning that if A knows B, then B also knows A.  In light of this, your "know each other" table can be thought of as implicitly containing more rows; for example, since you have a row for (1, 10), then the row (10, 1) is implied.  My results take into account these implied rows, and include all implied and non-implied rows in the results.

Filtering out rows which could be implied is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Thank you. That's what @Strawberry meant by " Cross join and outer join where null" I was working on that. I didn't want to create a human database but I can just VIEW it and use it after. Didnt know about VIEW ( new to sql ), very convenient.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first get all possible KnowEachOther-pairs and then select those that are not in KnowEachOther.

As you did not specify a table which would list all humans, you need to use union to combine the id_human1 and id_human1 from KnowEachOther. By joining the result to itself you will get all possible pairs.

The query will be simpler if you have a separate `humans` table.

```
select * 
from 
  (
    select id_human1 as id_human1
    from KnowEachOther
    union
    select id_human2
    from KnowEachOther
  ) humans1
  join
  (
    select id_human1 as id_human2
    from KnowEachOther
    union
    select id_human2
    from KnowEachOther
  ) humans2 on humans1.id_human1!=humans2.id_human2
where not exists (
 select *
 from KnowEachOther k
 where k.id_human1=humans1.id_human1 and k.id_human2=humans2.id_human2
)
order by humans1.id_human1, humans2.id_human2
```

Comment: This seems more verbose a solution than necessary

Comment: Indeed it is too verbose and gives wrong associations.
Here is the result:

id_human1|id_human2-
1|2-
1|12-
1|13-
2|1-
2|10-
2|11-
10|1-
10|2-
10|11-
10|12-
10|13-
11|1-
11|2-
11|10-
11|12-
11|13-
|12|1-
|12|2-
|12|10-
|12|11-
|12|13-
|13|1-
|13|2-
|13|10-
|13|11-
|13|12-

Comment: Was assuming the KnowEachOther works one way. If intention is that it works both ways you can modify the where clause to say:  `where (k.id_human1=humans1.id_human1 and k.id_human2=humans2.id_human2) or (k.id_human1=humans2.id_human2 and k.id_human2=humans1.id_human1)`

Answer (score 0):

Without a separate Human table, create a CTE using a `WITH` to simplify the logic of the final SQL.

```
 WITH HumanIDs AS 
        (SELECT
            [HumanID]
        FROM
            (
                SELECT id_human1 AS [HumanID] FROM @KnowEachOther
                UNION
                SELECT id_human2 AS [HumanID] FROM @KnowEachOther 
                WHERE id_human2 NOT IN (SELECT id_human1 FROM @KnowEachOther)
            ) x )
```

Then join the HumanIDs together creating all possible pairs.
Then remove any pairs that exist by using a `WHERE NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    h1.HumanID, h2.HumanID
FROM
    HumanIDs AS h1
    INNER JOIN HumanIDs AS h2 ON h1.HumanID <> h2.HumanID
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            KnowEachOther AS ke
        WHERE
            ke.id_human1 = h1.HumanID
            AND ke.id_human2 = h2.HumanID
    )   
ORDER BY
    h1.HumanID, h2.HumanID
```